# $m^2+2017=n^3$ has no solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Show that $m^2+2017=n^3$ has no solutions for positive integers $m,n$.

I'm having trouble tackling this one, especially since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2017}]$ isn't a UFD. We can write the equation as $m^2+45^2=n^3+8$ or $m^2+17^2=n^3-12^3$, but I can't do much with either.

Comment: add 8 to both sides. Can you factor anything now?

Comment: Probably it's not particularly useful, but if two such integers existed, then $m$ is even and $n\equiv1\pmod{4}$ just by mod 4 considerations.

Comment: By a similar argument $m$ is divisible by $7$ (again, not that this is likely to be useful...)

Comment: What is the source of the problem. Did you find and exercise in some textbook which claims that there are no solutions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your claim is false.

$$81060^2 + 2017 = 1873^3$$

Comment: May I ask how you found this?

Comment: I am lazy. Before trying to work on a problem, I want some numeric evidence. Sometimes I write something in C, or in PL/SQL, etc. This time I wrote a simple SQL statement in Oracle database. This is the only solution for n < 1.5 million.

Comment: @WillFisher The solutions are so small that a program could be written.

Comment: @WillFisher Here's the Python with no cute mod rules applied in a 100k x 100k search space: http://imgur.com/a/C35Xj

Comment: @lhf - I don't understand the question. Do you mean which version? "Oracle database" is a database product, I use version 11.2 but I don't know how that is relevant. Or do you mean what SQL statement? I can add that to my answer, but again, I don't know how that is relevant to the question and answer.

Comment: @mathguy, I meant, do you have a database for Mordell equations?

Comment: Lol No, I don't. I wrote a really simple SQL statement to check for solutions by brute force.

Comment: E_-02017: r = 2   t = 1   #III =  1
          E(Q) = <(877/49, 20910/343)> x <(1873, 81060)>
          R =  38.4895012680
           2 integral points
            1. (1873, 81060) = 1 * (1873, 81060)
            2. (1873, -81060) = -(1873, 81060)  at  http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL-

Comment: Could we prove that this is the only solution?

Comment: What Will Jagy shows is a claim that it's the only solution in positive integers. Go to that site and see if it helps.